# How I can know the version of the software included with each release?

Tags: release-management

I need to know the version of any piece of software included with Ubuntu and the ones that provides support before downloading and installing Ubuntu. I need to know what are the versions of all the packages included with Ubuntu. Is there such list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all the packages included in the disk images (iso or dmg) just reading the `.manifest` files, for example:

```
http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.manifest
```

This is the file with the manifest with all the packages and versions for `precise` the `ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64` image. For all the packages included in the release version you can use:

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/
```

replacing saucy for the codename of the release. Of course, there's also the `-updates` repositories, but the main one should be sufficient.